# ajax pagination using datatables

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

I am first loading 10 records and create html table and init datatable.
after that on click of paginated numbers want to send ajax request, it should fetch another 10 records and display into datatable.
Please help me if anyone having any idea about it.

Comment: For MySQL there is a Limit clause for select statements that allows you to give the starting record count and number of records

Comment: This example has anything you need: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the datatable use this: ( Be sure to change #example to match your table and data/arrays.txt to match your data source.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
    } );
} );
```

http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html